# question about read japanese filename in windows

Tags: python, github-actions

I have a file with japanese file name need to be read

```
202112_10エリア計.csv
```

it works fine on my windows pc, i just need to read it by:

```
pd.read_csv (file_path+'202112_10エリア計.csv')
```

however, when i was trying to use it on Github Action(still windows enviroment)
it got error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\202112_10\u30a8\u30ea\u30a2\u8a08.csv'
```

so, i think its because github action can not read japanese character
and i want to encoding it before read it

```
csv_name = csv_name.decode('utf-8')
```

and it got error again

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

so i was wondering if someone could help me achieve this? thanks in advance:)

Comment: string have is encode that make the bytes and bytes have decode that make them string

Comment: you can try with `csv_name.encode('utf-8').decode(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))` that should set the string it to the system [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) or some combination there off, otherwise I don't know